# Error in reading element of a vector in R

Tags: r

I would like to convert some numbers to words (so 5 becomes "five" etc). I am using `english` library to create a vector of integers that have been transformed into words. However, when I try to access some elements of my vector (elements after 100), I receive the following error:

`Error in UK && (d <- makeNumber(dvec)) > 0 : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'`

Here is my code:

```
library(english)
words <- as.english(c(1:1000))
words[999]
```

The aim is to access any element of a vector `words`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `english` class can be converted to `character`

```
as.character(words)[999]
#[1] "nine hundred ninety-nine"
```

The issue starts with 3 digit number onwards

```
words[100]
```

> Error in UK && (d <- makeNumber(dvec)) > 0 : invalid 'x' type in 'x
>   && y'

---

Checked for methods with `[`

```
grep('english', methods(`[`), value = TRUE)
#[1] "[.english"
```

So, there is an existing method to subset, but may be it is a bug

Comment: That's brilliant! Cheers!

Comment: Can't accept your answer atm but will do when it will allow me to.